# Launch a server and an IHM in different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, network-programming

I need your advice on a program I'm coding right now. First of all, let me present you what it is :

I design an IHM with button and stuff like this :

Here's my `main window` :
[image: Main Window]

When I click on the `QButton Supervision`, i'm going on this window :
[image: Supervision Window]

The IHM is finished, after I code a server, that works, and treat the frame receive. Now what I want to do is lauch the server and the IHM at the same time, and when I click on supervision, show the information that the server receive in the QTableWidget.

For doing this, I think I need : `THREAD` AND `SHARED MEMORY SEGMENTATION`.

`Thread` : To lauch the server and the IHM , and `Memory Segmentation` : to give to my IHM, the data that the server receive.

I try to lauch the server in the constructor of my `main window`, here's the code in my `main window` :

```
//Constructor
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //Start my window (initialisation of button code
...
    //Thread of the server
    std::thread t1(lancerServeur);
    t1.join();


}
//Server function lauch by thread
void MainWindow::lancerServeur(){
Server s;
    while(1){
    s.readData();
    }
}
```

`PROBLEM` : The server start but not the IHM, I don't understand why, because it is supposed to be in a thread ...

Also do you think shared memory segmentation is a good idea ? If yes, do you have a good link for me ?

Thanks.

Comment: You are block on `t1.join()` which waits for t1 to end before going out ouf your constructor

Comment: @jbh Ho it seems right, do you have a solution ? Because I begin in the utilisation of thread ...

Comment: Belloiel: Store your thread in a member variable instead of the stack. And let your server thread go, don't join before you really want to be sure it is ended by itself

Comment: @jbh Thanks, can you explain to me how to do this ? Because I don't understand how can we store a thread in member variable. Also what do you think of shared memory segmentation ? You can post and answer, I will accept it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your server reading thread is an infinite loop, you will never exit of it. So, a call to `join` will never return. Storing the thread object in a member variable ensures it will not be destroyed once you go out of scope.

```
//header file
#include <thread>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
//...

private:
    std::thread m_t1;
};

//source file

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //Start my window (initialisation of button code
...
    //Thread of the server
    m_t1 = std::thread(lancerServeur);
}
```

If you just want a thread runs by itself on its own and don't care that it is joinable, you can also decided to `detach` it.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //Start my window (initialisation of button code
...
    //Thread of the server
    std::thread t1 = std::thread(lancerServeur);
    t1.detach();
    //..going out of scope will not destroy the thread
}
```

Comment: You can also have a thread manager object or something else, this answer is better explained than mine.

Comment: @Mayerz: You are right to suggest a better usage of thread launching. This example is only provided for facility. I would not declare and launch daemon thread from a UI object.

Comment: Thank you, so if I want my thread of the server stop when I close my MainWindow, what function should I call on the thread ? And if you said what I do is not the best, what should I do better ?

Comment: There is no method for stopping a thread available in std::thread. Your thread must stop itself, thanks to synchronization mechanism available or once its job is done. I suggest you read a bit about the subject.

Comment: Well you can define a condition in your IHM thread who close the other thread and then stop his own exec and go back to the main execution.

Answer (score 1):

std::thread::join() blocks the current thread until the t1 thread finishes its execution.

You basically lock yourself into the t1 thread.

**What to do?**

store t1 somewhere else, so you can access it later, finnish what you were doing with the ihm thread etc. And when you are all set, access back t1 and call join().

What I see:

```
int main()
{
std::cout << "starting first thread...\n";
std::thread t1(foo);

std::cout << "starting second thread...\n";
std::thread t2(bar);

std::cout << "waiting for threads to finish..." << std::endl;
helper1.join();
helper2.join();

std::cout << "done!\n";
}
```